Why is the number of microstates corresponding to a macrostate even finite for an ideal gas in a box?
I was looking at the Sackur-Tetrode equation which gives an exact formula for the entropy of an ideal gas. I tried to relate it to Boltzmann's famous $$S = k_B \ln(W)$$ where $S$ is the entropy and $W$ is the number of microstates which correspond to the macrostate.
The Sackur-Tetrode equation suggests that e.g. if I have 1 particle of an ideal gas in a $1\text{m}^3$ cubic box at $300\text{K}$ then this system has some finite entropy, say $S^*$. This then suggests that the number of microstates the gas particle inside the box can occupy is $e^{S^*/k_B}$, which is also finite.
However this goes against my intuition because I think I can place the atom at any physical position within the $1\text{m}^3$ box (of which there are an infinite number of choices of) and also I am free to choose the direction of its velocity (the magnitude of the velocity is fixed by the internal energy since we're at $300\text{K}$ but the direction is freely variable), which again gives me a choice of an infinite number of vectors for the direction.
Taken together to me this suggests there are an infinite number of microstates that the gas particle can be in that all correspond to the same macrostate, so therefore the entropy should be infinite (because $\ln(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$) and not a finite number like the equation says. Where is my intuition going wrong here?

For the phase space, you should work with phase space volume..."number of microstates" is ill-defined, as you noted. This should be explained in any textbook. But this has been asked for sure on this site before.

Right, but then that's not unit invariant (assuming you meant replacing $W$ with phase space volume). I can change my units of measure and after taking logs this will add some constant to the calculated entropy.

It is defined up to an additive constant anyway.

You intuition is perfectly fine. The fundamental problem is that there is no way to describe our universe with classical physics. The underlying universe is quantum in nature, and whatever classical approximation must at least be semi-classical in order to be even qualitatively correct. Quantum theory the one that asserts that this sum is finite. If you are lucky, your lecturers would make you understand why there is no hope for a classical description of our universe.

@naturallyInconsistent I disagree. Statistical mechanics/physics is, after all, a "toolbox", and does not care if the world is "classical" or "quantum". If you define all quantities properly, there is no contradiction or so at all. The term "number of microstates" is just not defined for the case OP is discussing.

@TobiasFünke No, if you just learn things piecewise, you wont get to see why the framework requires quantum theory. It is only when you realise that there must be a coherent and consistent framework from which everything follows, that you realise that there is no way to get a classical description to work, and that quantum is the only possible route.

Quantum mechanics cannot "follow" from statistical mechanics (neither from these considerations nor from a common misunderstanding of Gibbs' paradox). I agree, though, that as far as we know, the world is quantum and not "classical".

For continuous systems, the definition slightly changes. I will quote the following definitions from some lecture notes on soft condensed matter (they are not online sadly):
Let $\Gamma=(\mathbf r^N,\mathbf p^N)$ denote a point in phase space, where each $\mathbf r_i$ is inside some volume $V$. The microcanonical probability distribution is given by
$$f(\Gamma)=\frac{\delta(E-H(\Gamma))}{\omega(E,V,N)}$$
where
$$H(\Gamma)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac {p_i^2}{2m}+U(\mathbf r^N)$$
and
$$\omega(E,V,N)=\int\frac{\mathrm d\Gamma}{N!h^{3N}}\,\delta(E-H(\Gamma))$$
This last expression is an integral over the surface in phase space where $H(\Gamma)=E$ and $h$ is a constant with units of angular momentum that makes the expression unitless. Here $N!$ is required to have extensive dependence of $N$ in the thermodynamic limit, and can be interpreted as a correction-factor that corrects for overcounting identical particles. Now, define
$$\Omega(E,V,N)=\int\frac{\mathrm d\Gamma}{N!h^{3N}}\,\Theta(E-H(\Gamma)).$$
This corresponds to the volume of all points in phase space such that $H(\Gamma)<E$. We also have $\omega=(\partial \Omega)/(\partial V)$.
We can then define the 'volume entropy' as
$$S_v(E,V,N)=k\log\Omega(E,V,N).$$
Or, we could define the more familiar Boltzmann entropy:
\begin{align}
S_B=k\log W=k\log\Delta E\,\omega.
\end{align}
Or the surface entropy:
\begin{align}
S_s=k\log\omega.
\end{align}
See also this question for the distinction between the different kinds of entropy.
